# How can I keep a java program running in the background?

Tags: java, background-task

I want to write a program that performs certain action when certain keys are pressed. The only way I know how to do this requires the java program to opened (or focused at least). How can I keep it running in the background so that it keeps listening regardless of which program/window I currently have open?

**EDIT:** I'm using Windows

Comment: Which OS is this targeting?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention this, I'm using Windows.

Comment: The problem here is that you have to intercept the keystrokes before the OS diverts them to the appropriate application's message pump. Normally it's the application with the focus that receives it. I'd be surprised if anyone here tells you how to do this since doing that is the foundation of so much malware.

Comment: You can't, not using  (only) Java, anyway.

Comment: Here you have a similar question and a good answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901224/listening-for-input-without-focus-in-java

Comment: What other way can I do it?