# Java easiest keylistener

Tags: java, input, console, keylistener

I know there was milions of questions  about that, but I can't understand most of them. I've seen that people make something like that:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    if (e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_Q)
        //do something
}
```

but keyPressed must override methos of some class to work or be runned in other thread. I really don't know how to do that. Can someone give me code of the easiest keylistener for java.
***It should work even when program is not focused*** (it's just console program).

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SquatCounter {

class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_Q)
            System.out.println("Key Q pressed!");
    }
}

JFrame jf = new JFrame("title");
public SquatCounter() {
    jf.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Key1 key = new Key1 ();
    SquatCounter test = new SquatCounter();
}
}
```

Comment: If it's a console program, I don't think a KeyListener will help you. Can you tell us more about why you think you need a KeyListener? What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a single char from the console in Java (as the user types it)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it)

Comment: KeyListener is part of Swing which means GUI not console. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: There is a tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html about implementing key listeners.

Comment: I don't want to type anything in console. I want make something like game hack? I want to turn it's functions on and off while playing.

Comment: Then, as stated, `KeyListener` is useless for you. You want to keep an open input stream.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30564519/1803551) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1066318/1803551).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you setup the JFrame, add a KeyListener like this:

```
JFrame jf = new JFrame("title");
jf.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
jf.setVisible(false);
```

(The `jf.setVisible(false);` stops the program window from appearing (only command line)

Then create a new class called `MyKeyListener` that `extends KeyAdapter`.

```
class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_Q)
            System.out.println("Key Q pressed!");
    }
}
```

**Now let me explain things a bit.**

First, when you create a JFrame, it has no default `KeyListener` attached. Therefore, we have to create a class `MyKeyListener` to do that.

Secondly, we extended KeyAdapter instead of implementing KeyListener because there are a lot more methods than what you need in there. You only need to **override** the `keypressed()` method when you extends KeyAdapter but you have to **implement** all (I think it's 3) the other methods that you **don't** need for your purposes.

Lastly, if you want to do other methods like `keyreleased()`, just add it in to the `MyKeylistener` class and it will work.

Hope this helps!

***EDIT: Per OP's request, it should be like this:***

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = "";

while (line.equalsIgnoreCase("q") == false) {
   line = in.read();

   System.out.println("Q is pressed!");
}

in.close();
```

Comment: I see what you try to tell me, but is it possible to have something like keylistener without program window?

Comment: @Konowy just do `jf.setVisible(false);`

Comment: I did as you wrote, but is seems not to work.
Need I call that method or something?
I made that class in my main class.

Comment: The OP wants a console program, not Swing. Besides, hiding the frame will not allow it to receive any key events.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `KeyListener`.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SquatCounter {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame("title") {{
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3); // EXIT_ON_CLOSE
    }};

    public SquatCounter() {
        jf.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
                if (e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_Q)
                    //do something
            }
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
                // different stuff
            }
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
                // more stuff
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SquatCounter test = new SquatCounter();
    }
}
```

**Doing something out of focus** has an answer here: [Stackoverflow: Listening for input without focus in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901224/listening-for-input-without-focus-in-java)

Comment: Um, I don't think so, it wouldn't make much sense if it did, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: The OP wants a console program, not Swing. Besides, hiding the frame will not allow it to receive any key events.