# java exclusive use of usb bar code reader on a windows machine

Tags: java

We have an application that has a bar code reader attached to the pc and uses the standard input when scanned.

The problem we are having is that someone gets on the machine, and lets say surfs the web, now when the bar code is scanned, it is in the browser not our app.

Is there a way to get control of the usb bar code scanner so when it is scanned, the input is entered into our app in a minimized window, not the current window?

Mike

Comment: Can we have a little more information about the reader? Manufacturer and model? It might be that there is no way of telling if the characters are coming from the reader or the keyboard. Perhaps if you gave some sample output from the reader (by scanning while in Notepad or something), that might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

John,
Sorry about the slow response.
We work with many manufacturers and models, they are HDI type of interface.
If I sent you a Notepad output it would be just 000000 (six numbers).

What we need is a way to exclusively control the USB port that the swipe is connected to we know when a card is swiped.

Keeping in mind that some one else is using the same computer to do web searches, check emails, ect.  They do not want to have to click on our app every time someone needs to swipe.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

First, I *think* you cannot block the barcode scanner to write the scanning result into the web browser since the scanner **is** a keyboard, too.

Second, there will be [no easy solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901224/listening-for-input-without-focus-in-java) as you have to listen for key presses in other windows (since you do not have focus the key presses will not be forwarded to your application).