# How to detect a pressed key globally, in a window without focus in java?

Tags: java, keyboard, background-process

I'm having a problem detecting pressed letters when the application is out of focus, I would like it to be running in the background and when I press a key outside the window it detects it, I saw something very similar in GameMaker Studio 2, called "keyboard_check_direct" but I can't find a way to adapt it to java, thank you very much.

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282801/detect-a-keypress-with-java-in-the-background

Comment: Thank you very much, the answers have been very helpful