# Register Key Event when not focusing on JavaFX application window?

Tags: java, javafx

This could very well be a dumb question, but I haven't found anything about it in the docs.

Let's say I have a JavaFX application with an EventFilter added that handles KeyEvents.

```
scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,
    keyEvent -> doSomething());
```

Would that EventFilter register that the user pressed a key, even if the user is not focused on the JavaFX GUI window itself?

For example: I want a hotkey to activate something in my app without the user having to navigate from the application they're using to focus on my JavaFx app.

I hope that's not too confusing, thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @user11924644! First, welcome to Stack Overflow! Secondly, can you please post some code snippets to aid someone in helping you?  You can surround code snippets in ``` ``` (triple ticks) to format it as code.

Comment: @Bwvolleyball Thank you! I added some code in the post. I hope that makes it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is nothing within JavaFX to my knowledge that allows for an unfocused window to be targeted with keypresses.

However, you don't need JavaFX to do this, just third party libraries. I personally can verify that the [JNativeHook library](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) works well for this purpose.

Read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901224/listening-for-input-without-focus-in-java/904448#904448) to get the gist of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you so much. Without going too much offtopic, do you know of any library that's similar to the JavaFX Robot (Robot simulates keyboard input) but is not a part of JFX?

Comment: Off the top of my head... Java.awt.robot is basically the same thing without javafx invooved

Comment: I will look into that. Thank you for your help